# Как в Select2 задать цвет фона у выбранного пункта?

Tags: select2

Как в Select2 задать цвет фона у выбранного пункта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заглянуть в панель разработчика и самому разобраться.

`.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]` - выбранный элемент.

`.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected]` - наведение на элемент.

Пример:

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css');

#js-select {
  width: 300px;
  
}

.select2-search--dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
  background: red;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  
  <select name="select" id="js-select">
    <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="Value 3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="Value 4">Value 4</option>
    <option value="Value 5">Value 5</option>
  </select>
```